# Disable gulp notifications?

Tags: notifications, gulp, laravel-elixir

I use gulp and laravel elixir for building a website. Everytime I do `gulp` or `gulp --production` in my editor (geany), 3 desktop notifications pop up. (gnome 3.18.2). Also when I do `gulp watch` the notifications appear.

Can I disable these messages or let them show up only in the terminal?

Comment: I think [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/elixir-disable-success-notifications) can help you. You only need to add `process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = true;` in first line of your `gulpfile.js`. I  checked that solution and it worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

add `process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = true;` in first line of your `gulpfile.js`.
and this line :

if you want disable only in local :

```
if (process.argv[2] == '--local') {
    process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = true;
}
```

Comment: High five! So annoying! :)

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Working as expected!.

Answer (score 0):

[Hamid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908687/994600) wasn't working for me, however I'm on **Windows 10** and found that I could disable the notifications from `gulp` by:

1. Opening Windows **Settings** > **System** > **Notifications & actions**
2. Then turning off **SnoreToast** notifications
   ([screenshot of **Notifications & actions** screen with SnoreToast turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5SSh.png))